# Sadaharu's form in Gintama

Tags: gintama

Since the Gintama anime recently ended, I dont think I saw what happened to Sadaharu after becoming small inside a sphere (of aura?). Will he always remain in that form now? Please clear  this question. Its been bugging my mind ever since I watched the last episode.

Comment: It has yet to be revealed. Last time Sadaharu was shown, Sadaharu was still small and Kagura was looking for a way to turn Sadaharu back to normal.

Comment: that is exactly whats bugging me. They cant leave sadaharu like that.

Comment: You're gonna have to wait until it is revealed then. As of now Sadaharu has become The Wanwan Gorilla-sensei Only Knows. TWGOK in short.

Comment: Well, Gintama did not actually end, the anime just used up all the materials from the manga. The manga is still ongoing, but it just moved from the weekly Shonen Jump to  the monthly Jump Giga, so it'll probably be a while before we get another Gintama anime.

Comment: so you mean gintama anime has not ended?